# How to get my parsed data from json data models

Tags: java, android, json, pojo

I am trying to show my data from  my data model to my activity.am  facing abit of a problemm trying to parse my data from my classes. any help will be appreciated.

This is my datamodel class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class datamodel{

    @SerializedName("threeWay")
    @Expose
    private List<threeWay> threeWay = null;
    private threeWay homeTeam;



    public threeWay getHomeTeam() {
        return homeTeam;
    }

    public void setThreeWay(List<dvlp.lamseybets.threeWay> threeWay) {
        this.threeWay = threeWay;
    }
}
```

This is my pojo class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class threeWay{

        @SerializedName("betDate")
        @Expose
        private String betDate;
        @SerializedName("competition")
        @Expose
        private Competition competition;
        @SerializedName("homeTeam")
        @Expose
        private String homeTeam;
        @SerializedName("awayTeam")
        @Expose
        private String awayTeam;
        @SerializedName("gameStarted")
        @Expose
        private Boolean gameStarted;
        @SerializedName("gameFinished")
        @Expose
        private Boolean gameFinished;
        @SerializedName("homeHalfTimeScore")
        @Expose
        private Integer homeHalfTimeScore;
        @SerializedName("awayHalfTimeScore")
        @Expose
        private Integer awayHalfTimeScore;
        @SerializedName("homeScore")
        @Expose
        private Integer homeScore;
        @SerializedName("awayScore")
        @Expose
        private Integer awayScore;
        @SerializedName("tip")
        @Expose
        private String tip;
        @SerializedName("risk")
        @Expose
        private Integer risk;
        @SerializedName("tipResult")
        @Expose
        private String tipResult;
        @SerializedName("betCategory")
        @Expose
        private String betCategory;
        @SerializedName("tipper")
        @Expose
        private String tipper;
        @SerializedName("_id")
        @Expose
        private String id;

        public String getBetDate() {
            return betDate;
        }

        public void setBetDate(String betDate) {
            this.betDate = betDate;
        }

        public Competition getCompetition() {
            return competition;
        }

        public void setCompetition(Competition competition) {
            this.competition = competition;
        }

        public String getHomeTeam() {
            return homeTeam;
        }

        public void setHomeTeam(String homeTeam) {
            this.homeTeam = homeTeam;
        }

        public String getAwayTeam() {
            return awayTeam;
        }

        public void setAwayTeam(String awayTeam) {
            this.awayTeam = awayTeam;
        }

        public Boolean getGameStarted() {
            return gameStarted;
        }

        public void setGameStarted(Boolean gameStarted) {
            this.gameStarted = gameStarted;
        }

        public Boolean getGameFinished() {
            return gameFinished;
        }

        public void setGameFinished(Boolean gameFinished) {
            this.gameFinished = gameFinished;
        }

        public Integer getHomeHalfTimeScore() {
            return homeHalfTimeScore;
        }

        public void setHomeHalfTimeScore(Integer homeHalfTimeScore) {
            this.homeHalfTimeScore = homeHalfTimeScore;
        }

        public Integer getAwayHalfTimeScore() {
            return awayHalfTimeScore;
        }

        public void setAwayHalfTimeScore(Integer awayHalfTimeScore) {
            this.awayHalfTimeScore = awayHalfTimeScore;
        }

        public Integer getHomeScore() {
            return homeScore;
        }

        public void setHomeScore(Integer homeScore) {
            this.homeScore = homeScore;
        }

        public Integer getAwayScore() {
            return awayScore;
        }

        public void setAwayScore(Integer awayScore) {
            this.awayScore = awayScore;
        }

        public String getTip() {
            return tip;
        }

        public void setTip(String tip) {
            this.tip = tip;
        }

        public Integer getRisk() {
            return risk;
        }

        public void setRisk(Integer risk) {
            this.risk = risk;
        }

        public String getTipResult() {
            return tipResult;
        }

        public void setTipResult(String tipResult) {
            this.tipResult = tipResult;
        }

        public String getBetCategory() {
            return betCategory;
        }

        public void setBetCategory(String betCategory) {
            this.betCategory = betCategory;
        }

        public String getTipper() {
            return tipper;
        }

        public void setTipper(String tipper) {
            this.tipper = tipper;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
}
```

And this is my fragment which I intent to display my data:

```
public class matchResult extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = matchResult.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String URL = "http://bets.herokuapp.com/api/get/20/coupons";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public List<datamodel> datamodels= new ArrayList<>();
    private StoreAdapter mAdapter;

    public matchResult() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    public static matchResult newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        matchResult fragment = new matchResult();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_match_result, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       datamodels = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new StoreAdapter(getActivity(), datamodels);



        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        resetNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        fetchStoreItems();

        return view;
    }

    private void fetchStoreItems() {
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Couldn't fetch the store items! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        List<datamodel> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<datamodel>>() {
                        }.getType());

                        datamodels.clear();
                        datamodels.addAll(items);

                        // refreshing recycler view
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error in getting json
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }


    class StoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StoreAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        private List<datamodel> datamodels;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView name, price;
            public ImageView thumbnail;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                name = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                price = view.findViewById(R.id.price);
                thumbnail = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            }
        }


        public StoreAdapter(Context context, List<datamodel> datamodels) {
            this.context = context;
            this.datamodels= datamodels;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,  int position) {
         datamodel games = datamodels.get(position);

            holder.name.setText((CharSequence) games.getHomeTeam());
            holder.price.setText((CharSequence) games.getHomeTeam());


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return datamodels.size();
        }
    }
}
```

This my API json response:

```
[
  {
    "couponDate": "2019-07-14T11:34:09.482Z",
    "couponComment": "GooD LucK :)",
    "couponNumber": 1,
    "_id": "5d2b134149db640017f8fda4",
    "overUnder": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T11:34:09.472Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "jh",
          "league": "jhj"
        },
        "homeTeam": "jh",
        "awayTeam": "hj",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "Over0.5",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "overUnder",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b143749db640017f8fda6"
      },
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "overUnder",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30043b2bc800172f5f3f"
      }
    ],
    "threeWay": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "threeWay",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30083b2bc800172f5f40"
      }
    ],
    "doubleChance": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "doubleChance",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30003b2bc800172f5f3e"
      }
    ],
    "goalGoal": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "goalGoal",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b300c3b2bc800172f5f41"
      }
    ],
    "halfTime": [
      {
        "betDate": "2019-07-14T13:24:19.804Z",
        "competition": {
          "country": "kenya",
          "league": "add"
        },
        "homeTeam": "da",
        "awayTeam": "ada",
        "gameStarted": false,
        "gameFinished": false,
        "homeHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "awayHalfTimeScore": -1,
        "homeScore": -1,
        "awayScore": -1,
        "tip": "1X",
        "risk": 0,
        "tipResult": "pending",
        "betCategory": "halfTime",
        "tipper": "reptile",
        "_id": "5d2b30113b2bc800172f5f42"
      }
    ],
    "bookingPts": [

    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

public class datamodel{

```
@SerializedName("threeWay")
@Expose
private List<threeWay> threeWay = null;
private threeWay homeTeam;



public threeWay getHomeTeam() {
    return homeTeam;
}

public void setThreeWay(List<dvlp.lamseybets.threeWay> threeWay) {
    this.threeWay = threeWay;
}
```

}

```
This is my sample of my log cat
''''''
2019-07-24 18:34:24.912 28808-28832/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
2019-07-24 18:34:24.912 28808-28832/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2019-07-24 18:34:27.414 28808-28839/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: close [socket][/10.0.1.230:46558]
2019-07-24 18:34:27.424 28808-28832/dvlp.lamseybets D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: lamseybets.herokuapp.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
2019-07-24 18:34:27.426 28808-28832/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: [socket][1] connection lamseybets.herokuapp.com/34.204.24.219:80;LocalPort=-1(5000)
2019-07-24 18:34:27.851 28808-28832/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: [socket][/10.0.1.230:46560] connected
2019-07-24 18:34:27.851 28808-28832/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
2019-07-24 18:34:27.852 28808-28832/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
2019-07-24 18:34:32.853 28808-28839/dvlp.lamseybets I/System.out: close [socket][/10.0.1.230:46560]

    2019-07-24 18:34:32.854 28808-28808/dvlp.lamseybets E/matchResult: Error: null

2019-07-24 18:34:32.866 28808-28808/dvlp.lamseybets D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{7e082e7 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@c9c33a1
2019-07-24 18:34:32.869 28808-28826/dvlp.lamseybets D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xa0adb000
2019-07-24 18:34:32.870 28808-28808/dvlp.lamseybets D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{1debd3d Toast,ident = 2}
2019-07-24 18:34:32.909 28808-28826/dvlp.lamseybets D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xa0adb000 initialize window=0x90dba000, title=Toast
2019-07-24 18:34:32.909 28808-28808/dvlp.lamseybets D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x90dba000)
2019-07-24 18:34:32.909 28808-28826/dvlp.lamseybets D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x90dba000,api=1)
2019-07-24 18:34:32.910 28808-28826/dvlp.lamseybets W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
```

Comment: Why your fields in datemodel class aren't Serialized? Only threeWay is..

Comment: the pojo generetad that file .. the three way i serialized my self

Comment: That's really weird, can you try to Serialize every field? Or maybe you can delete the ones that you don't use..

Comment: okey let me serialize every field ..

Comment: check this out have done that nothing is happenig